# Class Not Found java apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I need your favor. I am working on a web application in NetBeans with Apache Tomcat server. I have done lots of research to figure out the solution. I found some similar problems but I am not able to solve it. Please can you lend me your help with following error image.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Registration

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class Registration

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class Registration
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Registration
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.33 logs.
```

Comment: Where is your Registration class? It is saying that it can't find it, so the class isn't in the place where it suppose to be.

Comment: Looking at the exception, it seems that the Registration class is not under any package, make sure thats the case and change your web xml accordingly.

Comment: Well, my Registration class is in the path WEB-INF\classes specified by netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the information you provided that you don't have your class in the default package.

The error says:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Registration
```

Your `Registration` class must be in the default package and mapped in `web.xml` or annotated with [WebServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation (works in Tomcat 7).

Comment: @Actually, i have not defined any packages and this Registration class is in the default package defined by netbeans. I defined the mapping in web.xml as well.

Comment: Hello Guys! i created a package instead of default package and define its mapping in web.xml. It worked and thank you for you guidance.